# How do I break sturdy-looking rocks?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

I know that there are no HMs in Pokémon Sun and Moon. That said, two of the Pokémon in my party *do* know Rock Smash. However, I've encountered multiple "sturdy-looking rocks" at this point and I haven't been able to get past any of them. The game just says:

> It's a sturdy-looking rock. Maybe a powerful Pokémon could break it..."

What does it mean by powerful Pokémon, if the key isn't to use Rock Smash? Furthermore, how do I break sturdy-looking rocks in the water?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the end of Melemele Island, you will end up fighting the first Kahuna. After the battle, he gives you the Tauros pager. If you hold <kbd>B</kbd> while riding the Tauros and run into the sturdy rocks, they will break.

For sturdy-looking rocks in the water, you will need the Sharpedo Ride Pager, which you get from Grimsley on Route 15. Just like with Tauros on land, charging with <kbd>B</kbd> will break sturdy-lookings rocks in the water.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I was literally right about to do that, but I wanted to collect items first! >_<

Comment: There are also sturdy rocks in the water which you can break with _another_ Pokemon pager. I won't say what in case people would like to discover for themselves (even if the Pokemon used is obvious). As you progress through the game, different pagers will be gifted to open up new parts of the map, much like the HMs in old games. The advantage is that you won't need to carry around one or more [HM slave](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/HM_slave) Pokemon :)

Comment: @PhilD. I'm going to add that into this answer to prevent two "sturdy-looking rocks" questions